# C# - Execute code from a .NET DLL (Class Library) without referencing it?

Tags: c#, class, dll

I am trying to find a way in which I can execute code from a .NET DLL after my application has already been launched.  I have included some pseudo-code below that might try and explain what I'm trying to do.  I know it's probably a lot more complicated than I make it seem.

```
ClassLibrary myLibrary = new ClassLibrary("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\myTestLibrary.dll");
myLibrary.executeMethod("showMessageMethod", arg1, arg2, arg3...);
```

That's what I want to do although I understand it's likely far more complicated than that!

I would also like to make it clear that I **do understand** that you're meant to reference the library in your project etc... but my project requires that I don't do it this way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to load the assembly from disk, as follows:

```
Assembly myLibrary = System.Reflection.Assembly
    .LoadFile("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\myTestLibrary.dll");
```

After that you will need to get the proper type using reflection and invoke the proper method. It will be most convenient when that class you want to call implements an interface that is defined in an assembly that is referenced at startup:

```
Type myClass = (
    from type in myLibrary.GetExportedTypes()
    where typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    select type)
    .Single();

var instance = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(myClass);

instance.executeMethod("showMessageMethod", arg1, arg2, arg3...);
```

Comment: Hi, I have added a full example below, which shows how to actually call the methods. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I hope the following code example helps.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace zielonka.co.uk.stackoverflow.examples.Reflection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // dynamically load assembly from file Test.dll
            Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Test.dll");


            // get type of class Calculator from just loaded assembly
            Type calcType = testAssembly.GetType("Test.Calculator");


            // create instance of class Calculator
            object calcInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(calcType);

            // get info about property: public double Number
            PropertyInfo numberPropertyInfo = calcType.GetProperty("Number");

            // get value of property: public double Number
            double value = (double)numberPropertyInfo.GetValue(calcInstance, null);

            // set value of property: public double Number
            numberPropertyInfo.SetValue(calcInstance, 10.0, null);

            // get info about static property: public static double Pi
            PropertyInfo piPropertyInfo = calcType.GetProperty("Pi");

            // get value of static property: public static double Pi
            double piValue = (double)piPropertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);

            // invoke public instance method: public void Clear()
            calcType.InvokeMember("Clear",
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
                null, calcInstance, null);

            // invoke private instance method: private void DoClear()
            calcType.InvokeMember("DoClear",
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null, calcInstance, null);

            // invoke public instance method: public double Add(double number)
            double value = (double)calcType.InvokeMember("Add",
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
                null, calcInstance, new object[] { 20.0 });

            // invoke public static method: public static double GetPi()
            double piValue = (double)calcType.InvokeMember("GetPi",
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
                null, null, null);


            // get value of private field: private double _number
            double value = (double)calcType.InvokeMember("_number",
                BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null, calcInstance, null);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can load the assembly as detailed in Steven's answer, there is an other possibility.

You add references to the assembly in your solution, but you do not deploy the assemblies as part of the solution. This means you do not have to use reflection, instead you use the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event.

Your needs are not clear, but essentially this is a way of injecting a dll.

For instance, say you had dll to implement your database operations for each backend that you support.

When your code attempts to find the assembly, it looks in the usual places, if it has not been loaded and can't be found, the AssmemblyResolve event fires, and in there you dynamically load it from some accessible location based on some configuration option.

Accessible locations, can be a url, a totally different path, even network path. Not for this example obviously, but it could even be a blob from a database.

Answer (score 0):

First solution is to use:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
```

Second one is: [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Your answer is good for mentioning MEF as an option, but you should include a small example (don't just link to the codeplex location).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably a way to dynamically load an assembly at runtime.

Look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBoA36pwxJE